# Error when I run open -a Simulator on latest Xcode on Mojave

Tags: xcode, xcode-simulator

I'm on Mojave and updated my Xcode only.

Now when I run `open -a Simulator` in the terminal I get :

```
LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed for the application /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Simulator.app with error -10810.
```

with a Problem Report for Simulator dialog box :

```
Process:               Simulator [1735]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Simulator.app/Contents/MacOS/Simulator
Identifier:            com.apple.iphonesimulator
Version:               11.2.1 (912.4)
Build Info:            Indigo-912004000000000~81
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Simulator [1735]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2019-11-26 12:50:44.557 +0530
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.14.6 (18G1012)
Report Version:        12
Bridge OS Version:     4.1 (17P1081)
Anonymous UUID:        ECB481F4-CDED-82D5-E3F8-8E8D4935F21D

Sleep/Wake UUID:       1767E2FD-5142-42C2-8D1B-810ABF4725E1

Time Awake Since Boot: 7400 seconds
Time Since Wake:       120 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Reason:    DYLD, [0x4] Symbol missing

Application Specific Information:
dyld: launch, loading dependent libraries

Dyld Error Message:
  Symbol not found: _SimCarPlayPropertyKeyHasBackButton
  Referenced from: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Simulator.app/Contents/MacOS/Simulator
  Expected in: /Library/Developer/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSimulator.framework/Versions/A/CoreSimulator
 in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Simulator.app/Contents/MacOS/Simulator

Binary Images:
       0x10ea56000 -        0x10eae6ff7  com.apple.iphonesimulator (11.2.1 - 912.4) <668F9B50-AFF0-33BC-812E-39B176C2B4EE> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Simulator.app/Contents/MacOS/Simulator
       0x10eb21000 -        0x10ebb4ffb  com.apple.CoreSimulator (587.35 - 587.35) <0274C7CA-A3E7-3A39-BCA9-C117DF69F40A> /Library/Developer/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSimulator.framework/Versions/A/CoreSimulator
       0x10ec05000 -        0x10ecc2ff7  com.apple.SimulatorKit (1.0 - 570.3) <4FE40008-D5D4-3F27-9748-EC3873046020> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SimulatorKit.framework/Versions/A/SimulatorKit
.
.
.
Model: MacBookPro15,1, BootROM 1037.40.124.0.0 (iBridge: 17.16.11081.0.0,0), 6 processors, Intel Core i7, 2.6 GHz, 16 GB, SMC 
Graphics: kHW_IntelUHDGraphics630Item, Intel UHD Graphics 630, spdisplays_builtin
Graphics: kHW_AMDRadeonPro560XItem, Radeon Pro 560X, spdisplays_pcie_device, 4 GB
Memory Module: BANK 0/ChannelA-DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR4, 2400 MHz, SK Hynix, -
Memory Module: BANK 2/ChannelB-DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR4, 2400 MHz, SK Hynix, -
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x7BF), wl0: Mar 28 2019 19:17:52 version 9.137.9.0.32.6.34 FWID 01-36f56c94
Bluetooth: Version 6.0.14d3, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0
USB Device: USB 3.1 Bus
USB Device: iBridge Bus
USB Device: Touch Bar Backlight
USB Device: Touch Bar Display
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
USB Device: Headset
USB Device: Ambient Light Sensor
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)
USB Device: Apple T2 Controller
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 42.1
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 42.1
```

Comment: The error says you're trying to use CarPlay on a Mac simulator?  At least, that's my reading of it.  Have you tried to reinstall Xcode?

Comment: Previously iPhone XR used to open. I don't have anything related to CarPlay that I know of. I haven't reinstalled XCode.

Comment: This is now working after updating the latest Xcode today. It now launches iPhone 11 Pro Max.